# Can't get jQuery Ajax submit form working with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, submit

I am creating a Django web application which features a voting system similar to what is on this website.

Currently, when you click on an upvote or downvote arrow, I use jQuery to handle the change in color and the change in the vote score (number of votes). I basically take the vote score that was originally pulled from the database and add or minus one accordingly, and show this number. I am not updating the score from the database, so that the vote seems consistent to the user (in case other people cast votes while the user is on the site).

I am having trouble with the ajax part. Basically, when the user votes, I still want to send the upvote or downvote submission to the server and update the database, but not have the page refresh. When I don't add "return false" to the end of the ajax call, my database gets updated, but my page refreshes. However, when I add "return false" to the end of the ajax call, my page doesn't refresh, but the database also doesn't get updated.

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" class="voting-button" action="/sentence/vote/{{sentence.id}}/">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="submit" class="upvote_on" name="upvote" value="" />
                    <p class="vote-score">{{sentence.total_votes}}</p>
                    <input type="submit" class="downvote_off" name="downvote" value="" />
                </form>
```

It is a form with two submit buttons: one for upvote and one for downvote.

Here is the javascript for when you click on the upvote button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    //script to control arrows and the number of votes shown
        $("[name='upvote']").click(function(){
            if ( $(this).attr("class") == "upvote_off" ) {
                $(this).attr("class", "upvote_on");

                //If upvote is off and downvote is off
                if ( $(this).siblings("[name='downvote']").attr("class") == "downvote_off"){
                    var score = $(this).siblings(".vote-score").text();
                    scoreInt = parseInt(score)
                    scoreInt += 1;
                    $(this).siblings(".vote-score").text(scoreInt);
                } else { //if upvote is off and downvote is on
                    var score = $(this).siblings(".vote-score").text();
                    scoreInt = parseInt(score)
                    scoreInt += 2;
                    $(this).siblings(".vote-score").text(scoreInt);
                }

                $(this).siblings("[name='downvote']").attr("class", "downvote_off");

            } else {
                $(this).attr("class", "upvote_off");       

                $(this).siblings("[name='downvote']").attr("class", "downvote_off");

                var score = $(this).siblings(".vote-score").text();
                scoreInt = parseInt(score)
                scoreInt -= 1;
                $(this).siblings(".vote-score").text(scoreInt);
            }



            $.post(

            '/sentence/vote/{{sentence.id}}/',
            {
            name: "upvote",
            },

            function(response){
                $("#divText").text("hello world!");
            }
            )


        })
```

Basically, the gist of it is that the upvote button can have one of two classes: "uvpote_off" or "upvote_on", depending on whether the user upvoted or not. The if else statements are just to make change these states are changed correctly.

Here is my django view function, which the form sends to:

```
def vote(request, sentence_id):
p = get_object_or_404(Sentence, pk=sentence_id)

if 'upvote' in request.POST:
    try:
        v = Vote.objects.filter(voter = request.user).get(sentence=p)
        if v.score == 0:
            v.score = 1
        elif v.score == 1:
            v.score = 0
        else: #for case where v.score = -1
            v.score = 1 
        v.save()
    except Vote.DoesNotExist:
        v = Vote( voter =request.user, sentence=p, score=1)
        v.save()

elif 'downvote' in request.POST:
    try:
        v = Vote.objects.filter(voter = request.user).get(sentence=p)
        if v.score == 0:
            v.score = -1
        elif v.score == -1:
            v.score = 0
        else: #for case where v.score = 1
            v.score = -1
        v.save()
    except Vote.DoesNotExist:
        v = Vote( voter = request.user, sentence=p, score=1)
        v.save()


return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sentence.views.show_sentence_order', args=(p.sentence_order,)))
```

What exactly is the problem is here? I've been struggling with this for the last few hours and looked at a bunch of tutorials, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally gotten what I wanted to work. There were a number of errors with my previous code, one is that in the `$.post` function, i was passing in the url  `'/sentence/vote/{{sentence.id}}/'`.

However, this is what I should have done:

```
var loadURL = $(this).parent().attr("action");
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: loadURL,
                data: loadData,

    }); // End .ajax function

return false;   

})
```

Because there are a number of forms on the site, I had to grab the url from the parent of the submit button I was clicking to ensure it was the right form. I realized this after noticing that my requests were all "/sentence/vote//"

Then the other thing was about passing the CSRF token, along with every post request, as shown here in the official Django docus: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

I have to admit I don't fully comprehend this, but I copied the code into my script block, and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noted from your example, some of these are just my opinions on efficiency:

```
def vote(request, sentence_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Sentence, pk=sentence_id)
```

If this is an ajax call, and not used for anything else, you don't need the get_object function. Just get the object, since you know the vote objects exists, because you passed it in. I would, however, use the if request.is_ajax() method and raise a 500 otherwise.

```
v = Vote.objects.filter(voter = request.user).get(sentence=p)
```

instead you could write:

```
v = Vote.objects.get(voter = request.user,sentence=p)
```

Here:

```
    v.save()
except Vote.DoesNotExist:
    v = Vote( voter =request.user, sentence=p, score=1)
    v.save()
```

You can delete the first v.save() and move the second one out of the try except block:

```
except Vote.DoesNotExist:
    v = Vote( voter =request.user, sentence=p, score=1)
v.save()
```

I also think that the upvote and downvote are pretty much the same thing, and you should consider creating a class that instantiates this behavior for you, so you don't have to write as many lines. I realize 6-8 doesn't sound like much, but it's a good habit to get into.

Doing this:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sentence.views.show_sentence_order', args=(p.sentence_order,)))

will send the response to some other URL and view. I'm not sure what show_sentence_order does because you haven't posted it, but I'm assuming it will cause a refresh of the page.

When sending ajax back to the client, you simply do something that will look like:

```
return HttpResponse(some_object_probably_json_here, mimetype="application/json")
```

Of course, you will need to catch it from your javascript call, and I can't see where yours does that off hand.

I highly recommend reading this website:

http://lethain.com/intro-to-unintrusive-javascript-with-django/

and stepping through the entire tutorial.

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the pointers on efficiency. This is actually my first time writing a Django app, so still don't have a very efficient design for the code. The tutorial was very hlepful, it answered a lot of the questions I had with setting up ajax in django. The main problem was actually with passing the csrf_token as POST data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax. I'll post it as answer to further elaborate.

Comment: @WarAndPiece Thank you, if my post was helpful, accept the answer and vote it up, if it wasn't, leave it as is ;)